# React-Native - Dynamic State from JSON for Switch

Tags: json, filter, react-native, state

Hey there :) I got following issue by adding a filter Modal to my SearchView

> I constructed a `SearchPage` where several events can be listed. This all workes pretty fine. Now i am trying to add `filter` to my `SearchPage`. If i set the filter manually it works pretty fine -> Now my issue:
>
> **If i try to change the switch value of the Switch, it set´s back to the root because the state for the value is not set**

Steps i did explained:

> I am trying to open a `Modal` View where all my `filter` are listed and where i can set `true/false` by using a `Switch`. My idea was to fetch all `filter Settings` by creating a `JSON` for it:

```js
module.exports = {
  "filter":
      {
          "track": [
              {
                  "id": 1,
                  "description": "IoT & Living tomorrow"
              },
              {
                  "id": 2,
                  "description": "Smart & Digital Retail"
              },
              {
                  "id": 3,
                  "description": "Startups, Digital Culture & Collaboration"
              }
          ]
        }
  }
```

*The JSON above is just for expample - Normally its much larger and has more topics than just track*

> Now i import the `JSON` and save it at the `var filter`. I checked the data is in the right format here -> `filter.track -> All my JSON Objects`
>
> Now i created a my class with the `filter Modal`

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    ListView,
    Modal,
    StatusBar,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
    Switch
} from 'react-native';

var filter = require('../JSON/filter');

class PopoverFilter extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        // ds for the menu entries
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:   (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
            eventTracks: ds.cloneWithRows(filter.filter.track)
        }
        this.show = this.show.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Modal>
                         <ListView
                                style={styles.mainView}
                                renderRow={this.renderMenuEntries.bind(this)}
                                dataSource={this.state.eventTracks}/>
                        
            </Modal>
        );
    }

    renderMenuEntries(entry) {
        var switchState = entry.description;
        return(
            <View style={styles.switchView}>
                <Text style={[styleHelper.fonts.titleSize, styles.text]}>{entry.description}</Text>
                <Switch onValueChange={(value) => this.switchChanged(switchState, value)}
                value={this.state.switchState}/>
            </View>
        );
    }


    switchChanged(field, value) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[field] = value;
        this.setState(obj);
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
});

module.exports = PopoverFilter;
```

> Please ignore the missing Style and also there are more Objects in the Modal but its not important for this case.
>
> Most important is that i try to render the every Switch by the `renderMenuEntries` method and i give them all entries -> The  works just the Switch is not set right. As far as i try to change the value of the switch it is instant go back to its root. And no state is set.

*Maybe my solution is not possible and i have to make every state static - but this solution would be very good in case that i could set dynamic filter later without changing the whole code*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you describe is possible. There were a number of issues I encountered with your code:

1. In `renderMenuEntries` the value you were assigning to the `<Switch />` component was the *description* of the data item, instead of the expected boolean that the `<Switch />` component `value` expects. Further, this value was also referencing a property of `this.state` that didn't exist.
2. The `switchChanged` function was also just updating the component state using the data item's *description*

Using your code sample provided I created a new class from scratch named `PopoverFilter`. Instead of requiring the filter data within this component, it expects the data to come in via a component prop named `filterData`. This will promote reusability of the component to accept different datasets.

The code is heavily commented to help explain the concepts demonstrated. Here's the `PopoverFilter` class:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ListView,
  Modal,
  Switch,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class PopoverFilter extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    // bind relevant handlers up front in the constructor
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);

    // process the incoming filter data to add a 'selected' property
    // used to manage the selected state of its companion switch
    this._filterData = this.processFilterData(this.props.filterData);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

    this.state = {
      filterDataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this._filterData)
    }
  }

  processFilterData (filterData) {
    // don't mutate the filterData prop coming in
    // use map to create a new array and use Object.assign to make
    // new object instances with a new property named 'selected' initialized
    // with a value of false
    return filterData.map((item) => Object.assign({}, item, { selected: false }));
  }

  switchChanged (rowId, isSelected) {
    const index = +rowId; // rowId comes in as a string so coerce to a number
    const data = this._filterData;

    // don't mutate this._filterData
    // instead create a new array and new object instance
    this._filterData = [
      ...data.slice(0, index), // take everything before the target index
      Object.assign({}, data[index], { selected: isSelected }), // create a new object instance with updated selected property
      ...data.slice(index + 1) // take everything after the selected index
    ];

    // update the listview datasource with the new data
    this.setState({
      filterDataSource: this.state.filterDataSource.cloneWithRows(this._filterData)
    });
  }

  renderRow (item, sectionId, rowId) {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>{item.description}</Text>
        <Switch
          onValueChange={(value) => this.switchChanged(rowId, value)}
          value={item.selected}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  // just a test function used to dump the current state of the _filterData
  // to the console
  onPress () {
    console.log('data', this._filterData);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Modal>
        <ListView
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          dataSource={this.state.filterDataSource}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
          <Text>Get Filter Data</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Note this `PopoverFilter` class also renders a button that when pressed will dump out the current state of the data to the console so you can view it's current form.

Here's an example of how to use the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import filterData from './filter';
import PopoverFilter from './PopoverFilter';

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <PopoverFilter filterData={filterData.filter.track} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

Comment: Hi Mason, first thank you so much for your big and full reply. I will try to test your solution out and it looks pretty fine. I give u feedback as far as i implemented your solution. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Mason, so i had time to test your solution out and it fits perfect to what i wanted to do. Thank you very much for your detailed suggestion and the time you took. Also special thank to further information about what i can do better in my code :)

Comment: That's great Jonathan, I'm glad the code sample and tips helped you. If you're satisfied with this result, please make sure to mark it as the answer so others searching for the same problem can benefit from the solution.